# I want my Bootstrap form to be centrally aligned, I have used the standard classes of BS Form, but the form always aligned to left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center-align, twitter-bootstrap-form

> I used various classes for margin:0 auto, and for center-alignment but not worked.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 newsletter">
                <form action="#" method="post">                   
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-4">
                             <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-4">
                            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>
                </form> 
              </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add -offset- class to the div with col- classes. For example:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-6 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-4">
```

col-md-offset-4 will add extra space, so the input with label will be centered.
For further information read this [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

**UPD** You may also use flexbox. Apply this css style to your code:

```
.newsletter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

But keep in mind that you will need to remove bootstrap classes (col-md, col-xs etc) from the div with form-group class name. You can view the working example with flexbox [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzPXQa)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 newsletter">
                <form action="#" method="post">                   
                    <div class="form-group">
                             <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                        </div>
                </form> 
              </div>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
.newsletter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Check Demo [**here**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ALQRWr?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section-form">
      <div class="col-md-12 newsletter">
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section-form {
  max-width:550px;
  margin:auto;
}
```